LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods: 'InnerException' threw an exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException'
I recently tried to use libGit2Sharp within my .Net Project. It´s a x64-compiled dotnetFW 4.8 (c#7) application.
Sadly i got a  'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' threw from "NativeMethods" really quick.
Here ist my simplified debug code:
string workingdir = @"D:\<user>\repo";
string pullurl = "<some_pull_link>";
Repository.Clone(pullurl, workingdir); //<- threw the exception
using (var git_repo = new Repository(@"D:\<user>\repo")) {
    RepositoryStatus status = git_repo.RetrieveStatus();
    Commands.Checkout(git_repo, "int");
}

package refs:
<packages>
  <package id="LibGit2Sharp" version="0.30.0" />
  <package id="LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries" version="2.0.322" />

Error Stack:
'InnerException' threw an exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException'
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_clone(git_repository*& repo, String origin_url, FilePath workdir_path, GitCloneOptions& opts)
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Core/Proxy.cs:Row 278.
at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Repository.cs:Row 824.
at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath) in /_/LibGit2Sharp/Repository.cs:Row 758.
...
Target: Int32 git_clone(LibGit2Sharp.Core.git_repository* ByRef, System.String, LibGit2Sharp.Core.FilePath, LibGit2Sharp.Core.GitCloneOptions ByRef)

I tried to compile and add the native libGit2 source and set the compiled Assemblies as reference to my Project, but had no luck.
Anyone knows whats missing here?

"I tried to compile and add the native libGit2 source" Are you sure git_clone is exported?

How to check this?
So what i did gave me this : "git2.dll, pcre.dll, pcre16.dll, pcre32.dll, pcrecpp.dll, pcreposix.dll, zlib1.dll" thats what i tried to add without sucsess.  I compiled it quickly using vcpkg
Do i need to add/install the native lib otherwise aswell?
I don´t really know if the native libGit2 needs to be installed, cause i thougth they would be included in the LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries package.

Yeah, LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries should copy git2_xxxx.dll into libs\win32\x64, you don't need to compile it.

so i think it knows of the binaries but there is some kind of missing "git_libgit2_init".  I double checked and the file you mentioned exist and it also matches the file inside the detailed Stack trace:
Unexpected exception occurred: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for "LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods" threw an exception. ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: The entry point "git_libgit2_init" was not found in the DLL "git2-a418d9d". at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_libgit2_init() at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.InitializeNativeLibrary()...
